# json.net converting TimeZoneInfo with CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver incorectly

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My unit test fails when I try to convert TimeZoneInfo object to a JToken with the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver. None of the property names are lowercased. The weird part is this only affects TimeZoneInfo and not other classes like KeyValuePair (of the classes I have tested). I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or if it is a bug with json.net. I have tried it in C#4.0 with an older version and with the latest version 6.0.3 and both exhibit the same behavior.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void TimeZoneInfoConvertedCorrectly()
  {
     JToken actual2 = JToken.FromObject(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "test2"), JsonSerializer.Create(
        new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }));

     // these don't fail
     Assert.AreEqual(new JValue("test"), actual2["key"]);
     Assert.AreEqual(new JValue("test2"), actual2["value"]);

     JToken actual = JToken.FromObject(TimeZoneInfo.Utc, JsonSerializer.Create(
       new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }));
     // should fail but doesn't, right?
     Assert.IsNull(actual["BaseUtcOffset"], "All the properties should be camel cased");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeZoneInfo` isn't serialized using Json.NET's object converters. Implementation of `ISerializable` interface's `GetObjectData` method is used instead. When deserializing, a private constructor is used. .NET framework, obviously, doesn't care about options you set for Json.NET.

Your settings will be ignored when serializing objects of any type implementing `ISerializable`, having custom JSON converters which read/write properties manually etc.

If you want to customize serialization of such types, you need to write custom converters.

Comment: To disable this behavior you need to add the IgnoreSerializableInterface flag to the contractResolver.

Comment: @user1991909 I wouldn't recommend this. I can't guarantee that plain field/property serialization will work correctly if you do this. Fields have "m_" prefixes, properties don't include some data (adjustment rules, in particular). If a type implements `ISerializable`, there's propably a reason for this.